# Why am I experiencing visual corruption with Intel X4500 graphics card on 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, intel-graphics, fonts, desktop-environments

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit. After a while of using it, the screens will have rubbish and smudges as in the pic. [image]

Here is my card info and driver:

```
lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV635/M86 [Mobility Radeon HD 3650]

 lspci -k
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Memory Controller Hub (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 20e0
    Kernel driver in use: agpgart-intel
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset PCI Express Graphics Port (rev 07)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 2115
    Kernel driver in use: i915
```

Is there a fix for this? Thank you

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add your graphics card and the graphics driver you are using.

Answer (score 4):

I'm out on a limb here, but do you perchance have an **X3500 or X4500 Intel card** *and* an **odd amount of RAM** installed / unequal RAM sticks?

Because this is a **known issue** with those configurations: https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=28813

It affects Windows systems too, albeit less severely:

http://support.lenovo.com/en/documents/ht001223

**Linux 3.19 does not exhibit this problem,** so the solution is simply to `apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid` which will install 3.19 on your 14.04 LTS box.

Comment: That bug report mentions: "Workaround is now merged into drm-intel-nightly, should land in 3.19". Perhaps the OP can try to run a 3.19.x kernel or try out Ubuntu Vivid (15.04, in beta at time of writing).

Comment: Hah, that's great, thanks. @Louis, please, do let us know if you try 15.04 and it works for you :)

Comment: The latest Vivid 3.19 kernel can be found [here](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.19.3-vivid/). Just download `linux-headers-generic`, `linux-headers` and `linux-image-generic` debs for your arch.

Comment: @zhongfu: No need, just `apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid`. Which seems to have fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like that your graphic card driver is not up-to-date, or it has some bugs or conflicts with other software.
It can also be the graphic card itself; one time I blew up some capacitors on my graphic card, it started showing smudges like this for few days and then died completely.